# Size of Hindu Gods?

Tags: scripture, gods

Are there any scripture references for the size of Gods?

Did Rishis who had Darshan of Gods, describe their size?

Example: Mahabhrata Pandavas; were they of today's human size?

Comment: Do you mean size interms of numbers or description of measurements?

Comment: Any.. I just want to get the idea of how big Gods were.. if its mentioned in scripts anywhere.. descriptive  or  number..

Comment: Re: “Pandavas ; were they of today’s human size?” - No. They were taller. Height of humans in Kaliyuga is shorter. https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/12/2/12-16/

Comment: I don’t remember where but I read somewhere that Pandava were of greater height than present human beings. Lord Krishna showed his huge size to Arjun. Gods were big but how big that is not clear.